# How can I find ,Which InputField was recently updated?

Tags: dynamic, inputfield

I have 4 `InputFields`.I want to find which `InputField` was recently Updated out of all `InputFields`.For that purpose I wrote the following code.

```
 fValues = {Null, Null, Null, Null};
 {
  Table[
    With[
        {i = i},
        (
                InputField[
                            Dynamic[Part[fValues, i]],
                            Number,
                            ContinuousAction -> True
                        ]
            )
        ],
    {i, 1, 4}
],
Dynamic[fValues]
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please tell us why do you keep using so much whitespace with your code formatting? I am simply curious.

Comment: @IstvánZachar For my code maintenance  and understanding purpose,every time I following indentation Styels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the second argument to `Dynamic`:

```
DynamicModule[{fValues, msg, processChanges},
 fValues = {Null, Null, Null, Null};
 msg = "No change yet";
 processChanges[field_, oldvalue_, newvalue_] := 
  msg = Row[{field, " was changed from ", oldvalue, " to ", newvalue}];

 {Table[With[{i = i}, (InputField[
      Dynamic[Part[fValues, i], processChanges[i, fValues[[i]], fValues[[i]] = #] &],
      Number, ContinuousAction -> True])], {i, 1, 4}],
  Dynamic[fValues], 
  Dynamic[msg]}
 ]
```